# sort multidimensional array by 'parent/child' relationship

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative

```
I have an array that looks like this:


[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 111
        [parent_id] => 222
        [field_1] => Main document
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 123
        [parent_id] => 222
        [field_1] => Main document
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 777
        [parent_id] => 111
        [field_1] => Child document
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 345
        [parent_id] => 222
        [field_1] => Main document
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 789
        [parent_id] => 123
        [field_1] => Child document
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 567
        [parent_id] => 345
        [field_1] => Child document
    )
```

As you can notice there are main documents and child documents in the field 1. Child document's [parent_id] is equal to main document's [id]. How can i sort them all by id and parent id so after every main document should be child document? I know that I should loop through it but there are something that i can't hold on and it's not sorting by the way I want.

This is how it should look like:

```
  [0] => Array
    (
    [id] => 111
    [parent_id] => 222
    [field_1] => Main document
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
    [id] => 777
    [parent_id] => 111
    [field_1] => Child document
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
    [id] => 123
    [parent_id] => 222
    [field_1] => Main document
    )

  [3] => Array
    (
    [id] => 789
    [parent_id] => 123
    [field_1] => Child document
    )

  [4] => Array
    (
    [id] => 345
    [parent_id] => 222
    [field_1] => Main document
    )

  [5] => Array
    (
    [id] => 567
    [parent_id] => 345
    [field_1] => Child document
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need to do is divide the initial array into two parts: the main documents array and the children documents array. Then just iterate over those arrays and compose a new array where main documents are followed by a sequence of children elements.

Beware that this was written in php7.4 and I might have used some syntax that is not available in previous version of php.

```php
// extract main documents and sort them by id
$main_documents = array_filter($input, fn ($document) => $document['field_1'] === 'Main document');
usort($main_documents, function ($a, $b) {
    return ($a['id'] <=> $b['id']);
});

// extract child documents and sort them by parent id
$child_documents = array_filter($input, fn ($document) => $document['field_1'] === 'Child document');
usort($child_documents, function ($a, $b) {
    return ($a['parent_id'] <=> $b['parent_id']);
});

$output = [];

// go through each main document and insert it into the output array
foreach ($main_documents as $main_index => $main_document) {
    $output[] = $main_document;
    // go through all children and see whether they are a child of current main document
    foreach ($child_documents as $child_index => $child_document) {
        // if they are then insert this child after the main element
        if ($main_document['id'] === $child_document['parent_id']) {
            $output[] = $child_document;
            // delete inserted child element from the children array so that next iteration can be faster
            unset($child_documents[$child_index]);
        }
    }
    // delete current main element from the array so that next iteration can be faster
    unset($main_documents[$main_index]);
}
```

There is also a shorter version that operates on the initial input array:

```php
$output = [];
foreach ($input as $main_index => $document) {
    if ($document['field_1'] === 'Main document') {
        $output[] = $document;
        unset($input[$main_index]);
        foreach ($input as $subloop_index => $subloop_document) {
            if ($document['id'] === $subloop_document['parent_id']) {
                $output[] = $subloop_document;
                unset($input[$subloop_index]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My answer isn't very efficient though - having nested loops is never a good practice but if performance is not an issue in your code or the effects are negligeble then I think this should do it.

Comment: I forgot to add that the names of 'Main documents' are not the same. We must to use only id and parent id to compare and sort them.

Comment: if the names of main documents are different for everyone then you  have to add some additional flag to signify whether document is main or not and compare against that in the loops. 
something like ['id' => 0, 'parent_id' => 100, 'name' => 'doc', 'is_main' => true]

Comment: @paperman if my answer helped you please consider marking it as a solution, thanks